# Can I insert backing fields for properties with a specific implementation?

Tags: postsharp

I'm trying to create an attribute with PostSharp to implement specific backing fields of properties. However I did not find any helpful answers in the documentation, official examples or here on SO.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
[WrappedProperty]
public int MyProperty { get; set; }
```

will compile to

```
private WrapperClass<int> _generatedBackingField_myProperty;

public int MyProperty 
{
    get => _generatedBackingField_myProperty.Value;
    set => _generatedBackingField_myProperty.Value = value;
}
```

Is there any way to achieve this with PostSharp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, you can use `LocationInterceptionAspect` to intercept properties.
So the code would look like this:

```
[PSerializable]
public class WrappedProperty : LocationInterceptionAspect
{
    private WrapperClass<object> _backingField;

    public override void OnGetValue(LocationInterceptionArgs args)
    {
        InitBackingField();

        args.Value = _backingField.Value;
    }

    public override void OnSetValue(LocationInterceptionArgs args)
    {
        InitBackingField();

        _backingField.Value = args.Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please note that only one instance of the aspect will be created per target property. Essentially, the backing field in this case will act as a static field. You need to implement IInstanceScopedAspect if you want to have a new instance of the aspect for each new instance of the target class. For more details see https://doc.postsharp.net/aspect-lifetime

Comment: Thank you, that's good to know, although a static instance was sufficient in my case